# Why is my /var/lib/docker dir huge?

Tags: docker

I'm a backend software developer, and we use docker at work.
On my work machine, if I:

- Stop and delete all docker containers (even the stopped ones only visible with `-a`)
- Delete all docker images (even the intermediate ones only visible with `-a`)
- Delete all docker volumes

And my `docker system df` shows:

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          0         0         0B        0B
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

My `/var/lib/docker` dir is still huge:

```
/var/lib/docker - 54.8GB
/var/lib/docker/volumes - 4.3GB
/var/lib/docker/overlay2 - 12.4GB
/var/lib/docker/1001.1001 - 38.1GB
```

Is this normal? Can I clean this up somehow?
Running `docker system prune --volumes --force` didn't help.

Comment: What’s your operating system and file system?

Comment: Not sure why it matters, but I'm on PopOS 22.04, on ext4

Comment: it matters because Docker picks a storage driver for your file system. For example, for BTRFS, there’s this bug: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27653

Comment: @FlorianWendelborn interesting. I'm guessing a BTRFS issue wouldn't apply to me though. Any reason my setup might be using so much space?

Comment: I have no clue why, just wanted to point out that OS/FS is important here